# Why does eclipse stop on lines not executed when debugging a groovy class

Tags: eclipse, debugging, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When debugging a groovy class in GGTS 3.2.0 the debugger stops at lines that are not executed.

```
def debuggerExample() {
    def s = "hello"
    if (s.contains("hello")) {
        println "hello found"
    } else {
        println "goodby"
    }
    render "All Done"
}
```

In the above example, I put a breakpoint on the first line, "def s = hello". The debugger stops as on that line as expected. I then choose step over a few times. The debugger stops on both println statements. Only the first println really gets executed. It's frustrating to think I cannot trust the debugger. I hope I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Nothing is wrong.  This is a limitation of groovy.  It does not always produce a correct source locations for its class files.  You are likely hitting a variant of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4505.  We've fixed some of these problems, but more situations keep cropping up.

That being said, I tried to reproduce using Groovy 1.8.6 and 2.1.5 and cannot.  The debugger only stops on the expected line numbers.  What versions of Groovy, Groovy-Eclipse and Eclipse are you using?